# NameError: uninitialized constant - Un-allowed syntax in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two resources that I'm trying to join - Package and Listing through a join table SubmittedPackage. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and Rails 3.2.1 with PostgreSQL 9.1.3. The models look as follows.

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submitted_packages
  has_many :listings, :through => :submitted_packages

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submitted_packages
  has_many :packages, :through => :submitted_packages

class SubmittedPackages < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :listing
```

In Rails Console I keep getting *NameError: uninitialized constant Listing::SubmittedPackage*

If I replace the *SubmittedPackage* resource with *Drum* it will work (this of course includes having the appropriate table created and so forth).

Is :submitted_packages in conflict with something in Rails or ActiveRecord?

Any ideas why this is breaking?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: As a work-around I explicitly defined the :class_name for the has many relationship in the Listing and Package model. This has at least gotten things working, however, it's still is unclear to me why it was necessary to begin with. What Rails or Ruby naming convention was being broken by `:submitted_packages` ?

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submitted_packages, :class_name => 'SubmittedPackages'
  has_many :listings, :through => :submitted_packages

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submitted_packages, :class_name => 'SubmittedPackages'
  has_many :packages, :through => :submitted_packages

class SubmittedPackages < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :listing
```

Comment: You have a typo: `has_many :submitted_packages, :class_name => 'SubmittedPackage**s**'`. Your class name is plural, and it should be singular, i.e. `SubmittedPackage`. Rails just trying to find table named `submitted_packagess` and didnt find it (I suppose, :)).

Comment: @MarkGuk It's actually working just fine as you see it there. The version at the top where I didn't explicitly define the :class_name is where the problem lies. Thx for taking a look though!

Comment: But in your original problem code you also have wrong names for your model.

Comment: Hi, please make a simple test, rename your model to its singular form(SubmmitedPackage) then remove the :class_name and tell us the results

Answer (score 1):

If SubmittedPackage is the JoinTable, I guess it should have many listings, but I'm seeing just many packages and many submitted_packages.

HTH

Comment: Good catch. I completely botched the join table contents for some reason... The corrections have been made above, along with workaround fix. The original issue remains unexplained though!